# Subclass init method only calls base initializer method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a derived class whose `__init__` method only calls `super().__init(...)`. However, the list of arguments to the super class is very long, which makes for a long list of mostly boiler plate:

```
def __init__(self, dataset, updater=None,
                 start_date=None,
                 end_date=None,
                 fill_missing_only=False,
                 total_sync: bool = False,
                 force: bool = False,
                 allow_missing: bool = False,
                 backfill=''):
        super().__init__(self, dataset, updater,start_date, end_date,fill_missing_only,total_sync,force,allow_missing,backfill)
```

Is there a way to remove this and have the subclass call the base's init() method automatically?

Comment: use `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs): super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

- Just omit the `__init__` method in the subclass - if you don't in fact override anything.
- Use

  ```
  def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  ```

  if you do some other things besides the `super().__init__` call but don't need all arguments.

Comment: However, the OP is making type annotations on the parameters, and maybe its imortant those are preserved. The *args, **kwargs way do away with the function signature - annotations and all. Preserving that is non obvious, and if you find out a nice way, this would become a great answer even if the question is not that much.

Comment: @jsbueno. You could just copy the annotations, e.g., via a metaclass. Also, the first option will not need any extra work in that regard.

Comment: I don't do anything else in the method other than the super() call. If I omit the __init__ method in the subclass, will the super() method still get called? I was under the impression that the super().__init__() method does not get called automatically.

Comment: @user1742188 Yes. If you don't override a method (including `__init__`) then the first found (see [pythons method-resolution-order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)) superclass-method is called (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to to would be to remove the child's `__init__` altogether. The parent's `__init__` would be called automatically and annotations would be preserved. Remember that `__init__` is just a method and is therefore subject to MRO just like every other method. This approach only works if the child `__init__` has the exact same signature as the parent and does not require any additional functionality.

If the child has the same signature for `__init__` but does not require additional arguments, you can do something like this:

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff here
    super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)
    # Do stuff here
```

The only issue here is that the parent's annotations are not preserved in this case. You can copy over the `__annotations__` attribute from the parent directly if this matters to you, since a function's `__annotations__` is a mutable and assignable dictionary. The easiest way to make sure this is done consistently would probably be with a decorator:

```
def copy_annotations(parent_fn):
    def annotator(fn):
        fn.__annotations__ = parent_fn.__annontations__
        return fn
    return annotator

...

@copy_annotations(Parent.__init__)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If the child does not have the same signature as the parent (i.e., it has additional parameters), try to put those parameters first. For example, if this is the parent's `__init__` signature

```
def __init__(self, dataset, updater=None,
                 start_date=None,
                 end_date=None,
                 fill_missing_only=False,
                 total_sync: bool = False,
                 force: bool = False,
                 allow_missing: bool = False,
                 backfill=''):
```

you could define the child's as follows:

```
def __init__(self, child_param1: int = 0,
                 child_param2: bool = False,
                 *args, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff with child_param1, child_param2
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you need to mix the order up (so that the child arguments are not all first), you may have to do some tuple math to get the desired result. For example, if `dataset` has to be the first argument to the child `__init__`, you could define it like this:

```
def __init__(self, dataset,
                 child_param1: int = 0,
                 child_param2: bool = False,
                 *args, **kwargs):
    # Do stuff with child_param1, child_param2
    super().__init__(*((dataset,) + args), **kwargs)
```

This works because `args` is always a `tuple`, so you can prepend `(dataset,)` to it before unpacking. This technique will also work if you compute some of the arguments to the parent based on the child's arguments.

If you still want to preserve annotations, the decorator to do this will be marginally more complex. Instead of copying the parent's `__annotations__` attribute, you will want to merge it in with the existing dictionary:

```
def copy_annotations(parent_fn):
    def annotator(fn):
        original = fn.__annotations__
        fn.__annotations__ = parent_fn.__annontations__
        fn.__annotations__.update(original)
        return fn
    return annotator
```